# How to sort the records (order by) in my case

Tags: php, sql, sql-order-by

Hi I am trying to to sort my match by data, but something is wrong, I do not know where to put `ORDER BY data DESC` in my code.

data is a pool in my table when i have a data with time. If I put on the end of the line with `data_in` the code stop working when i put 2 data (`data_in` `data_out`) I put also behind `WHERE 1=1` and also stop working, so how to do that?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE 1=1 ";   

if ($name != ''){
    $query.=" and name like '%$name%' ";
}

if ($number != ''){
    $query.=" and number like '%$number%' ";
}

if ($person != ''){
    $query.=" and person like '%$person%' ";
}

if ($data_in != ''){
    $query.=" and data_in >= '{$data_in} 00:00:00'::timestamp ";
}

if ($data_out != ''){
    $query.=" and data_out <= '{$data_out} 23:59:00'::timestamp ";
}

if ($case != ''){
    $query.=" and case like '%$case%' ";
}           

$result = pg_query($query);
```

Comment: You'd put `ORDER BY` after your entire `WHERE` clause.  What have you tried and how did it "stop working"?

Comment: Also `data_in` condition needs to be changed like this:- `$query .=" and data_in >= ". date('Y-m-d H:i:s' , strtotime($data_in));` And `data_out` condition needs to be change like this: `$query .=" and data_out <= ". date('Y-m-d H:i:s' , strtotime($data_out));`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should not add 1=1 as it will show all records. You can remove that. after you can add order by after all if condition as below:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE ";   
$whereQuery = [];
if ($name != ''){
        $whereQuery[] = " name like '%$name%' ";}

if ($number != ''){
        $whereQuery[] =" number like '%$number%' ";}

if ($person != ''){
        $whereQuery[] =" person like '%$person%' ";}
if ($data_in != ''){
        $whereQuery[] =" data_in >= '{$data_in} 00:00:00'::timestamp ";}
if ($data_out != ''){
        $whereQuery[] =" data_out <= '{$data_out} 23:59:00'::timestamp ";}
if ($case != ''){
        $whereQuery[] =" case like '%$case%' ";}           

$completeQuery = $query.implode(" and ", $whereQuery)." order by data";  
$result = pg_query($completeQuery);
```

Apart, your query is open for SQL injection. Instead of concating variable, you should bind variables.

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: Everybody thank you a lot, I used first solution $query .=" ORDER BY <column name here> <ASC OR DESC>"; and this is working like i want - thank you all

Answer (score 0):

A separate line, which goes just before the `$result = ...` line:

```
$query .= " ORDER BY data DESC "
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order by data by placing "ORDER BY" after conditions and before using pg_query(). 
You can use following code.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE 1=1 ";   

if ($name != ''){
        $query.=" and name like '%$name%' ";}

if ($number != ''){
        $query.=" and number like '%$number%' ";}

if ($person != ''){
        $query.=" and person like '%$person%' ";}
if ($data_in != ''){
        $query.=" and data_in >= '{$data_in} 00:00:00'::timestamp ";}
if ($data_out != ''){
        $query.=" and data_out <= '{$data_out} 23:59:00'::timestamp ";}
if ($case != ''){
        $query.=" and case like '%$case%' ";}           

$query.="ORDER BY data_in DESC";
        $result = pg_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

After the end of all the clause  (in you case the where clause )

```
  $query.=" and case like '%$case%' ";}           

  $query.="  order by  my_column1, my_column2 ,  ,,, my_last_col ";}     

  $result = pg_query($query);
```